# Is there a way I can have an object take up multiple grids in Windows UA?

Tags: windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make my first app, and I'm having a little trouble with the grids. I'm trying to make the left side of the screen a map, and the right side 2 boxes/grids. I'm not sure if there is a way to have an object within multiple grids or how to just setup a layout like that (basically a + with the left line gone)

So far, this is the code I gotten for the layout.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- map -->
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make an element "take up" multiple grids but you can make it span multiple cells by setting `Grid.RowSpan` or `Grid.ColumnSpan` as appropriate.

e.g.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height= "*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Map will take up left hand side -->    
    <Map Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

    <!-- top right -->
    <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" /> 

    <!-- bottom right -->
    <List Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" /> 

</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that out in a little bit, and I will let you know if it works.